# Absolute position content disappears when sibling div is hidden

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I am building a site that has a welcome screen and then when you enter it plays a video.  On the welcome screen, there is a greeting and a "begin" button, and clicking the "begin" button dismisses the welcome overlay and plays the video. Here's the basic thing that I have working:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnmorrow/ua5Lvme8/5/

```
<video muted id="mainvideo">
        <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/thepapertrail/prototype/shortvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
    <div class="overlay" id="welcome-overlay">
        <div class="container above-overlay">
            <div class="row vertical-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                    <p>weclome to</p>
                     <h1>The Title Area</h1>

                    <p>more info here and then a link <a href="http://google.com">Here</a>
                    </p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" onclick="entersite()">Begin</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then

```
function entersite() {
    $("#welcome-overlay").fadeOut(1500);
    var video = $("#mainvideo");
    video[0].play()
}
```

However, there is this problem that when the overlay disappears, the video does as well. I think it has something to do that is is absolute positioned and when there is no sibling content, the dimensions are all screwed up.

Is this what is happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: Add `html,body{
    height : 100%;
}`

Comment: You are absolute positioned inside something you have not defined a height of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the body's height is **defined in percent**. The computed height will be 0, until you define a height to the parent, which is here the `html` tag.

Add:

```
html {
    height: 100%;  // This is the root tag => 100% of viewport's height
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/ua5Lvme8/17/)**

Alternatively, you can use the `vh` (viewport's height) unit, that does not rely on parent's height:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Supported from version 9 in Internet Explorer. [Browser support in detail](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked perfectly.